# Override a span hover using CSS

Tags: css, hover, html

I'm trying to change the hover of my spans. For some reason I need to use the same id's for all of `<li>` tags that contain my spans, so what happens basically is all the spans I created has the same parent id:

```
<li id="li_id">
    <span><a href="/some/link.html">Link title</a></span>
</li>
<li id="li_id">
    <span class="anotherlink"><a href="/another/link.html">Another Link title</a></span>
</li>
```

I've checked on how to override id's using classes, similar to this one:
[Can I override a #id ul li behaviour with a class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238477/can-i-override-a-id-ul-li-behaviour-with-a-class-definition) , but I can't seem to make them work.

**CSS:**

```
#primary_nav #home li#li_id>span:hover {
    background-image: url(this_image.png);
}

//This is for my first link
#primary_nav #home li#li_id .anotherlink >span:hover {
    background-image:url(another_image.png);
}

//This is for the other link.
```

Is my syntax correct? It' does not seem to be working right now and I don't know if the CSS for the other link is actually correct.

**NOTE:**
I know it seems a bit wierd doing this, as the process should be the other way around( 1 class, different id's) but what I'm basically doing is for an existing site, and I willing to do some unorthodox fixes like this, because we're going to replace the entire site with a new one, so I just need to make sure this site gets updated until the replacement site arrives.

Comment: Using ID's multiple times in your markup is invalid. There is no _"some reason"_ why this should happen. Use classes instead.

Comment: You answered your own question. See kleinfund's comment.

Comment: @kleinfreund sadly the previous developer did it, and instead of redoing all of the spans by replacing the identical id's with a single class, I was hoping if I could just work a way around it, since I'm only adding 1 new span.

Comment: Haha! There is a problem. I can fix it, but I'm too lazy. Come on! Just do it.

Comment: But why would you want to avoid that? You can leave the ID there and add a class to the parent ul and select something like this: `.list li {...}`

Comment: What is the use of those `<span>`s? Also, an auto-replace of `id` to `class` is pretty easy!

Comment: Just do it for the sake of non-laziness, even if you could do it without either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two CSS IDs is incorrect. They are supposed to be unique. Use classes if you want to use styling multiple times. Always remember this, Classes are for multiple usage, IDs are for single, unique usage.

Answer (score 0):

Since doing the right thing is always hard, I've decided to change the id's of all the spans, and just made quick changes using CSS and added all of the new id's to a single id selector.

```
 #primary_nav #home li#li_id-1 , #primary_nav #home li #li_id-2 {...}
```

Everything seems to be ok now, but I also realized that what I did was inefficient since I could have grouped it in a single class instead of placing all of the id's in a single selector.